# Installing regionally restricted packages on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, vpn, openvpn

So I've been trying to install Skype* but it didn't work because it's restricted in my region by the original company, so I tried to install the OpenVPN package but it's also restricted in my region. VPNOneClick didn't work either because it needs the Chromium Package which is also restricted :"D , and i couldn't connect succefully to a PP2P VPN, could pp2p be restricted too ?

So does anyone know any other solutions ?

*Installing Skype from other sources doesn't really solve the problem as there are other restricted packages I need to install like Ubuntu extras which contains Adobe flash player which is also restricted.
** I've tried both apt-get install and Ubuntu software center, I live in Syria.

Comment: For others to help, it might be useful to know what country you are in. Also, an example of how you have tried to install these packages might help too - since it isn't obvious what steps you have taken to try and install these packages. For example, are you using the `Ubuntu Software Centre`, or using the command line `apt-get install`, or are you trying to download the packages only from their website and running the `.deb` or archive package.

Comment: All three ways have failed , I'm in Syria ..

Comment: Have you tried using a different mirror server to see if that works? Open up the `Software & Updates`, you can also type `software-properties-gtk` in the terminal to open it. Where it says `Download from:` pick `Other` and select a different server. See if that helps.

Comment: You could also try asking fellow Syrians to see if they can help: http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/ubuntu-sy/, they also have a forum here: http://sy.ubuntuforums.org/

Comment: I'll try and let you know if it worked , thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it works out for you.